# enable HTTPS with self signed certificate on Sprint Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to launch web server with HTTPS on Spring Boot 1.4 ( and on 2.0.X). But I fail to connect to started server.

Here is my steps:

1. Add SSL properties to application.yml

```
     server:
       ssl:
         enabled: true
         key-store: classpath:keystore.jks
         key-store-password: password
         key-password: password
         key-alias: tomcat
       port: 8443
```

2. Generate self sign certificate on src/main/resources

   `keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA  -keystore keystore.jks

After run of application

```
 `mvn clean install && java -jar target/audiochat.war
```

Then in browser https://localhost:8433 (Chrome, Firefox, Edge)

```
   ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH
```

I was try to test SSL handshake

```
 openssl s_client -connect localhost:8443
CONNECTED(000001A8)
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 308 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID:
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key:
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1522596727
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
28412:error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure:s23_clnt.c:769:
```

Any ideas on correct setup of HTTPS on SpringBoot ?

Comment: I used [this](https://drissamri.be/blog/java/enable-https-in-spring-boot/) link

Comment: I did exactly same things. But with no luck.

Comment: Did you found a solution ?